# How to get CEdit (or CWnd) text in debug time

Tags: c++, oop, debugging, visual-c++, mfc

When I debug my project, and a `CEdit` object's text is changed, I want to see the new value. But the watch window doesn't display a text member.
Where the text is stored?

**EDIT:** I forgot to write that I use Visual C++ 6.0 ('98 edition)

The tree of CEdit in the watch window seems as this:

```
m_editBox
|  
+ [CWnd]  
  |  
  + CCmdTarget  
  + classCWnd
  + m_hWnd  
  + wndTop
  + wndBottom
  + wndTopMost
  + wndNoTopMost
  + m_hWndOwner
  - m_nFlags
  - m_pfnSuper
  - m_nMsgDragList
  - m_nModalResult
  + m_pDropTarget
  + m_pCtrlCont
  + m_pCtrlSite
  + _messageEntries
  + messageMap
+ CWnd
  |
  + CCmdTarget
  + m_hWnd
  + m_hWndOwner
  - m_nFlags
  - m_pfnSuper
  - m_nModalResult
  + m_pDropTarget
  - m_pCtrlCont
  - m_pCtrlSite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question where a window's text is stored upfront: I don't really know, and neither does any given window. To get to that information you would have to ask the window manager instead.

All information pertaining to a window is stored in an internal structure maintained by the window manager. The window manager is implemented by Win32k.sys and consequently those internal structures reside in kernel memory. A `HWND` serves as an index into a table controlled by the window manager. Even though the table entries are mapped read-only into user-space memory it is fairly tedious to get the information you want.

So far, so bad. However not all is lost yet. You can still get the information you need.

The easiest option would be to use Spy++ (Spyxx.exe). It ships as part Visual Studio and helps in retrieving window specific information, among other aspects it will show a window's text. Given your requirements you would go to *Spy* -> *Find Window...* (or press <kbd>[Ctrl]</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and enter the window's handle (in hex without the 0x-prefix). The information however does not automatically refresh. You need to click the *Refresh* button manually.

If you want real-time information inside Visual Studio's debugger you would have to write a debugger expression evaluation addin. Expression evaluators are not officially supported by Microsoft. As such there is no official documentation. [How to write a custom native visualizer DLL for Visual Studio 2012 debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545418/how-to-write-a-custom-native-visualizer-dll-for-visual-studio-2012-debugger) provides helpful information if you want to go down that route. An expression evaluator displaying a window's text entry would look like this:

HwndEEAddin.h:

```
// HwndEEAddin.h : main header file for the NatvisAddIn DLL
//

#if !defined( INC_HWNDEEADDIN_H_ )
#define INC_HWNDEEADDIN_H_

#pragma once

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
#include <windows.h>


#define ADDIN_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

/* DebugHelper structure used from within the */
typedef struct tagDEBUGHELPER
{
  DWORD dwVersion;
  BOOL (WINAPI *ReadDebuggeeMemory)( struct tagDEBUGHELPER *pThis, DWORD dwAddr, DWORD nWant, VOID* pWhere, DWORD *nGot );
  // from here only when dwVersion >= 0x20000
  unsigned __int64 (WINAPI *GetRealAddress)( struct tagDEBUGHELPER *pThis );
  BOOL (WINAPI *ReadDebuggeeMemoryEx)( struct tagDEBUGHELPER *pThis, unsigned __int64 qwAddr, DWORD nWant, VOID* pWhere, DWORD *nGot );
  int (WINAPI *GetProcessorType)( struct tagDEBUGHELPER *pThis );
} DEBUGHELPER;

/* Exported Functions */
ADDIN_API HRESULT WINAPI AddIn_HWND( DWORD dwAddress, DEBUGHELPER *pHelper, int nBase, BOOL bUniStrings, char *pResult, size_t maxResult, DWORD reserved );

#endif  // !defined( INC_HWNDEEADDIN_H_ )
```

HwndEEAddin.cpp:

```
#include "HwndEEAddin.h"

#include <strsafe.h>


ADDIN_API HRESULT WINAPI AddIn_HWND( DWORD dwAddress, DEBUGHELPER* pHelper, int /*nBase*/, BOOL bUniStrings, char *pResult, size_t maxResult, DWORD /*reserved*/ )
{
  HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

  HWND hWnd = reinterpret_cast< HWND >( dwAddress );
  if ( hWnd != NULL )
  {
    bool bGotWindowText = false;

    CHAR asciiWindowText[ 128 ] = { 8 };
    if ( IsWindowUnicode( hWnd ) )
    {
      WCHAR buffer[ 128 ] = { 0 };
      if ( GetWindowTextW( hWnd, buffer, ARRAYSIZE( buffer ) ) )
      {
        if ( WideCharToMultiByte( CP_THREAD_ACP, 0x0, buffer, -1, asciiWindowText, ARRAYSIZE( asciiWindowText ), NULL, NULL ) > 0 )
        {
          bGotWindowText = true;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if ( GetWindowTextA( hWnd, asciiWindowText, ARRAYSIZE( asciiWindowText ) ) )
      {
        bGotWindowText = true;
      }
    }

    if ( bGotWindowText )
    {
      hr = StringCbPrintfA( pResult, maxResult, "{pText=\"%s\"}", asciiWindowText );
    }
  }

  return hr;
}
```

To register the addin in Visual Studio 2010 and above you have to copy the .dll alongside the following file to %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Visualizers.

HwndEEAddin.natvis:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">

  <!-- Place this file and the AddIn-DLL to this folder: %USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Visualizers\ -->

  <Type Name="HWND__">
    <DisplayString LegacyAddin="HwndEEAddin.dll" Export="_AddIn_HWND@28"></DisplayString>
  </Type>

</AutoVisualizer>
```

In Visual Studio versions prior to 2010 you have to edit autoexp.dat by adding the following entry to the [AutoExpand] section:

```
HWND__ = $ADDIN(HwndEEAddin.dll,_AddIn_HWND@28)
```

The .dll must be in the devenv.exe directory or on the PATH. Otherwise you will have to use the fully qualified path name. Additional information for Visual Studio Expression Evaluators prior to VS 2010 can be found at [Customizing the Visual Studio Debugger Display of Your Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730838.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why is it so important to hide so simple information? Why won't the `MFC` object carry it?

Comment: @Aharon `CWnd`-derived classes are a thin wrapper around `HWND`, the native handle to identify windows. The information and layout of the underlying structure (`WND`) is not exposed to client code to implement a layer of abstraction. It allows Microsoft to change the internal `WND` structure at any time without breaking client code, that accesses the public API (`GetWindowText` in this case). Abstraction is the process of hiding complexity, which is a good thing from a system architect's point of view, however unfortunate it may appear to a developer who wants to see those details.

Answer (score 0):

The actual text is held in the control's somehow associated memory which is not directly accessible to you. You only have control's handle `HWND` wrapped into `CEdit` class. In order to get text from there you need to do from code `CEdit::GetWindowText` well in advance into local memory, and then inspect it with the debugger.

Comment: While debugging I have no call to `GetWindowText`, so I can't execute it. In addition, I have no problem to use `memory` window, but I have to know **where** am I supposed to watch in.

Comment: The point is that Watch window won't show it. It shows you data from the class pointer down to `m_hWnd` member, and text is yet "behind" it.

Comment: I understood it. But I don't know where in `m_hWnd` I'll find it, since watch window only shows `unused` with an int value. If I watch in `memory` I want to know the offset I should use from the `m_hWnd`'s pointed address.

Comment: Having a handle, the only think you can do it to send a message to this window, or use some API against it. This requires you to execute code. You cannot find it on Memory window using `m_hWnd` value.

Comment: I can't imagine it. Doesn't `CEdit` use its `m_hWnd`? Clearly it access `HWND` struct or something else to put the text in. I want to follow this track to look in debug time what is the text value. Impossible?

Comment: The text is managed by the EDIT control and not by the `CEdit` instance. The CEdit instance is a wrapper around the Windows EDIT control. I don't know how many more times Roman needs to tell you, but the `CEdit` control does not hold the text. It has to obtain it on demand. Any decent debugger will invoke a method for you in a watch window or evaluate dialog.

Comment: You are already given the track to follow. Call `CEdit::GetWindowText`, or if you prefer - send `WM_GETTEXT` message to this window. This is what `CEdit` would itself do. Wrapper class does not access control's internals directly as you are assuming, so that you could do the same in debugger having a snapshot of the process on pause.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But how many time **I** have to tell **you**? It's clear that `CEdit` instance jumps to an address stored somewhere, and maybe jumps a thousand times again, until it arrives at the text string. Please tell me how can I jump and follow its ones. Where is the address stored?

Comment: *It's clear that CEdit instance jumps to an address stored somewhere, and maybe jumps a thousand times again, until it arrives at the text string.* No, that's not how it works.

Comment: How can it be clear if you are asking this question to *make* it clear.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK. I understand now. But I still wonder. If it works through a message to `CDialog`, so the `CDialog` itself knows where the string is stored, doesn't it? Eventually clearly happening here some process eventually reach the string. If the application does, even through windows debug can be done. Am I mistake again?

Comment: The only thing that knows where it is stored is the code in the Win32 library that implements the `EDIT` control. No MFC object knows where the string is stored.

Comment: @RomanR. Clearly it's clear! As I wrote also to David. Something **does** happen in the process, and the string **is** stored somewhere. How does the process access there? If not through `CEdit` instance, so it uses another way, but the way **does** exist. What is the way? It's not a random one. (And it isn't fair that you downvote this question only because I argue with you.)

Comment: I downvoted the question for a legit reason: this question does not show research effort. To add to that you are ignoring three people who tell you how it really works.

Comment: @Roman Out of the three people that are - allegedly - in the know, not a single one explained how it really works. Instead you insist that the EDIT control manages the memory, when it doesn't even know where the text is stored.

Comment: @Tim first of all your comment is incorrect. EDIT control knows where text is and manages this memory. CEdit instead is not a control and does not know it. Second, from the comment to your answer above - even though it's marked as answer - it's clear that your explanation is not really helpful to the poster (although the explanation is really good and supposedly and hopefully helpful for further readers). Good luck.

Comment: @Roman The entire [`WND` structure](http://winterdom.com/dev/ui/wnd) including the memory pointed to is controlled by the window manager and lives in kernel space. If an EDIT control needs to retrieve its text it calls `GetWindowText` (a *window manager* API) passing in its `HWND` and a buffer to receive the data. This is true for both a plain EDIT control as well as MFC's `CEdit` or really any window identified through a `HWND`. In fact, a window doesn't even keep track of its own `HWND`; MFC's `CWnd`-derived classes have to store it separately.

Comment: I stand corrected on EDIT's control of text/caption part. So the text is even deeper. The rest of your commetn makes things even more confusing because you put EDIT and CEdit as equivalents (though it's clear from other comments that you did not mean that).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the new value, then you have to use a variable and retrieve the text from the window.

```
CString text;
GetDlgItemText(ID, text);
```

Comment: It's not what I asked. I'm now in debug time, want to find through `debug windows` the text value. If I can't find it in watch, instruct me where I will be able to.

Comment: You can't!. That's the point. The text is stored in the window, not in the MFC object of type CEdit that wraps an edit control. You could use Spy to watch the window. It will show you the text.

Comment: What's the problem with using GetDlgItemText ? YOU are in charge, YOU are debugging and YOU can put GetDlgItemText in YOUR program while your are debugging it.

Answer (score -1):

CEdit's "GetWindowText" method LITERALLY sends a Windows Message to get the text, not a function call with simple accessor methods to the text..  The m_hWnd is a "handle" to some data structure within the deep internals of the O/S where only the window's O/S code knows how to retrieve the text.

I wish it was simpler, but MFC is just a wrapper around the Win32 API.  You might try using C#, it does a better job of presenting the UI as objects (vs. wrappers around indirectly accessed C/Pascal/assembly structures)

Comment: CEdit's `GetWindowText` calls `::GetWindowText`. This may or may not send a message. If it does not send a message it will - technically - invoke a simple accessor to the text.