# Can I control the number of digits displayed in debugger windows for float and double variables?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, natvis

In Visual Studio 2012, I'm looking for a way to customize the default display of floating point types in the Autos, Locals, and Watch windows. I'm familiar with the Native Visualizer (Natvis) utility, but don't see any debugger formatting facilities to accomplish this. Likewise, I'm not aware of any means to override the default display of any primitive types (aside from enabling hex).

The goal would be to create display strings with fewer digits expanded for types corresponding to points, geometric vectors, etc, but still have all the precision show up when I expand the types. So for example I might have a variable of a point type display as `(0.000, 1.234, 2.429)` instead of `m_x = 0.00000000, m_y = 1.234245213...` in the middle column of the Autos window.

I looked through the format specifiers at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx), but don't see a way to control floating point precision.

Comment: See perhaps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf0e8s14.aspx

Comment: Can you get each value as a string (or convert it ) before displaying it? if yes, I may have a solution. Waiting for your answer..?

Comment: @KhaledHassan I could, and in many places we do that for debug output, but for widely used types I don't want to change the actual source. I was really looking for a way to tune the way the debugger presents doubles.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks. The native visualization file is awesome, but unfortunately it doesn't appear add any additional options for displaying raw numerical values that weren't already available in the autos or immediate windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is really no way to do this fine grained level of a change in C++ debugging.  In a managed language it would be possible in some limited scenarios (when the primitives were fields of objects and annotated with special `[DebuggerDisplay]` attributes).  For C++ though this type of customization just doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. Would it make sense to have an option in the menu near where hexadecimal display is available to tweak the precision? Especially for situations where I see lots of values in scientific notation at once, it hurts my head to separate important digits (i.e. the leading ones and the exponent) from unimportant values (all the junk in the middle).

Answer (score 14):

Although it doesn't appear to be supported in [their documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx), we have used the following definition to shorten the numbers (in VS 2015):

```
  <Type Name="MyVec3d">
    <DisplayString>{vectorX,g}, {vectorY,g}, {vectorZ,g}</DisplayString>
  </Type>
```

Comment: Yes, it works for me, but not with original VS 2015 distribution. I needed to update to service pack 2. I don't know whether the feature was introduced in update 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2):

Primitive types cannot currently be NatVizzed. However, if the specific primitives you're wanting to look at are members of another type that you can watch, you can apply formatting to that type, e.g.

```
<!-- displays the double value as 0.000 -->
<Type Name="DoubleHolder">
  <DisplayString>{(int)myDouble}.{(int)(myDouble*1000) % 1000}</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

Comment: Sadly, this won't work.  Consider how it will display the value 1.005: you'll see "1.5", which is misleading at best.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Overlord Zurg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26613960/12299940), display the value of `m_x` with three digits as follows:

```
<Type Name="Point">
  <DisplayString>
    {(int)m_x}.{(int)(10*m_x) % 10}{(int)(100*m_x) % 10}{(int)(1000*m_x) % 10}
  </DisplayString>
</Type>
```

To account for negative numbers as well:

```
<Type Name="Point">
  <DisplayString>
    {(int)m_x}.{(int)((m_x&lt;0?-1:1)*10*m_x) % 10}{(int)((m_x&lt;0?-1:1)*100*m_x) % 10}{(int)((m_x&lt;0?-1:1)*1000*m_x) % 10}
  </DisplayString>
</Type>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much control over this. We were able to get something a *little* bit better than the default view, however, by casting our doubles to floats for the preview:

`<DisplayString>{{x={(float)x} y={(float)y}}}</DisplayString>`

We left them as doubles in the unfolded version so that you can see the true values. This was enough for us to pack four or five values horizontally, instead of the usual three. This still has some disadvantages: The last couple of digits on the float will be garbage, and might make you think you have precision errors when in fact you don't. However, until Microsoft gets around to adding proper formatting specifiers for numeric output, this is perhaps the best we can do.

Incidentally, you can probably get a similar "chopped precision" by casting your floats to ints, if the values are typically large enough.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this that I know of is to write a native visualizer DLL.  See [this answer to the question "How to write a custom native visualizer DLL for Visual Studio 2012 debugger?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11545420/322152).

I have successfully used that, and the sources linked in that answer, to write custom visualizers that display the floating point members of various types with the precision I want.