# SQL Server debugger shows float numbers in scientific notation

Tags: sql-server, debugging, watch, scientific-notation

In my PC I have some SQL Server version installed from 2008 R2 to 2017.

In all cases when I debug SQL scripts or stored procedures the debugger shows float numbers in scientific notation instead of decimal notation. This happens in SSMS and also in Visual Studio 2019. Any suggestions?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: The 1.34 float value converted to decimal is 1.3400000000000000799360577730112709105. Is that what you are expecting? I don't think there is a documented way to control the display format in SSMS or VS. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690265/can-i-control-the-number-of-digits-displayed-in-debugger-windows-for-float-and-d).

Comment: For example for 120.56 debugger show me 1.2056000000e+02 instead of 120.56. Is this normal?

Comment: Mine is 95605 and it is shown as 9.5605000000012e+004. And 50 is shown as 5.000000000000000e+001. It is not normal, is it?